# R: update.formula limit to 512 chars

Tags: r

I am trying to "paste " together a formula to use in the mob function of party.  This means the formula will be of the form y ~ x1+ ...+xM | z1+..zN.

I am doing some preliminary fits of y ~ x1+ ...+xM, then want to add the conditional part of the equation using update().

Here's the test code:

```
var1 <- 1:78
x1 <- paste("x", var1, sep="")
f1 <- paste("f", var1[1:10], sep="")                                

# use first 77 variables
fmla <- as.formula( paste("y ~ ", paste(x1[1:77], collapse=" + ", sep=""), sep=""))
fmla2 <- update(fmla, paste(". ~ . | ", paste(f1, collapse= " + "), sep=""))

# CHANGE x to all 78 variables
fmla <- as.formula( paste("y ~ ", paste(x1, collapse=" + ", sep=""), sep=""))
fmla2 <- update(fmla, paste(". ~ . | ", paste(f1, collapse= " + "), sep=""))
```

I have run this in Windows and Linux (64 bit) and both fail when using all 78 terms (and anything more than 78 terms).  The error message contains **Error in parse(text = x) : :1:514: unexpected ')'**.

Changing the length of the names of the x variables will break the update() with fewer variables, but always with an error referring to just more than 512 characters.

Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for showing sample code and a clear question.

Answer (score 4):

Since this seems like a string length problem, it's simple to remove some non-essential characters, like spaces around the plus, i.e. `collapse= "+"`.

This works:

```
fmla2 <- update(fmla, paste(". ~ . | ", paste(f1, collapse= "+"), sep=""))

fmla2
y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + 
    x12 + x13 + x14 + x15 + x16 + x17 + x18 + x19 + x20 + x21 + 
    x22 + x23 + x24 + x25 + x26 + x27 + x28 + x29 + x30 + x31 + 
    x32 + x33 + x34 + x35 + x36 + x37 + x38 + x39 + x40 + x41 + 
    x42 + x43 + x44 + x45 + x46 + x47 + x48 + x49 + x50 + x51 + 
    x52 + x53 + x54 + x55 + x56 + x57 + x58 + x59 + x60 + x61 + 
    x62 + x63 + x64 + x65 + x66 + x67 + x68 + x69 + x70 + x71 + 
    x72 + x73 + x74 + x75 + x76 + x77 | f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 + f5 + 
    f6 + f7 + f8 + f9 + f10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for these replies, but they all miss the important part of using update() on the formula.

I need to use update because the first formula is being updated itself before pasting the conditional part of the formula.

One cannot use as.character() on the formula because as.character() has a ~500 char limit.  One way to work around this is to use deparse() on the first formula once its finalized.

```
fmla.string <- gsub(" ","",paste(deparse(fmla), collapse=""), fixed=T)
fmla2 <- as.formula( paste(fmla.string, paste(f1, collapse= " + "), sep=" | "))
```

Thanks to Duncan Murdoch and r-help for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

This is workaround.

```
var1 <- 1:78
x1 <- paste("x", var1, sep="")
f1 <- paste("f", var1[1:10], sep="")
as.formula(paste("y~",paste(x1,collapse="+"),"|",paste(f1,collapse="+")))
```